# Principal Component Analysis Summarization by the mean

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

Let’s consider $$ S=\{x_1 , . . . , x_N \} $$ with $$ x_1 , . . . , x_N ∈ R^d . $$ How can i prove that the solution of 
$$
argmin_{b∈ R^d} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}||x_i-b||^2
$$
is given by 
$$
b=\bar x=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i
$$
That is, the mean is the best vector summarizing/representing a sample set in the least-squares sense.

Comment: You are missing a sum in the objective, no?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, it's true, thank You, corrected :)

Comment: Differentiate the objective wrt $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic general result (not really related with PCA).

You only need to write

$$ \sum_i ||x_i - b||^2=\sum_i ||x_i - \overline{x} + \overline{x}- b||^2=
\sum_i ||x_i-\overline{x}||^2 +n ||\overline{x}-b||^2 $$

where the last equation arises because the crossed product is zero: $\sum_i c \, (x_i - \overline{x})=0$ (where $c$ is a constant vector, and the product is a scalar product).

Then, it's clear that the sum is minimized when the second term is zero, i.e. when $b=\overline{x}$